# Bash null binary operators

Tags: linux, bash, binary-operators

A recent test I took had a question on the output of the following `bash` command:

```
var=; [ -n $var ]; echo $?; [ -z $var ]; echo $?
```

The results are `0` and `0`, indicating the return codes for both unary operators had no errors. This means `$var` resolves to both `null` (empty) and 'non-null' (not empty), correct?

How is this possible?

Comment: Those are unary operators.

Comment: `info coreutils test invocation`    
16.3.4 String tests

Answer (score 3):

No, it means that `[` is unfixably broken. In both cases `$var` evaluates to nothing, and the commands simply execute `[ -n ]` and `[ -z ]` respectively, both of which result in true. If you want to test the value in the variable itself then you must quote it to have it handled properly.

```
$ var=; [ -n "$var" ]; echo $?; [ -z "$var" ]; echo $?
1
0
```

Comment: It is not `unfixably broken`; it just has non-intuitive behavior.  `[ -n ]` correctly reports that the string `-n` is not null, and `[ -z ]` correctly reports that the string `-z` is not null.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to surround $var:

```
$ [ -n "$var" ]; echo $?
1
```

Remember that the closing square bracket is just syntactic sugar: you don't need it. That means your line:

```
$ [ -n $var ]; echo $?
```

will expand to (since $var is empty):

```
$ [ -n  ]; echo $?
```

The above asks: "is the string ']' non-empty?" And the answer is yes.

Comment: While `[` is not syntax and in fact a synonym for the `test` command, you do need to use the closing `]` with `[`.

Answer (score 1):

It's surprising indeed. If you were to try the same with the bashism `[[` syntax, you'd get `1` and `0` as results. I reckon this is a bug.

```
var=; [[ -n $var ]]; echo $?; [[ -z $var ]]; echo $?
```

or, as Ignacio points out and as in fact I have always been doing intuitively, with defensive coding and quoting:

```
var=; [[ -n "$var" ]]; echo $?; [[ -z "$var" ]]; echo $?
```

It's surprising to me that `[` behaves this way, because it's a builtin:

```
$ type [
[ is a shell builtin
```

---

Just did a little test and the system command `[` behaves in the same broken way as the builtin. So probably it's buggy for compatibility:

```
var=; /usr/bin/\[ -n $var ]; echo $?; /usr/bin/\[ -z $var ]; echo $?
```

Comment: `[` has a lot of legacy behavior which cannot be modified, due to scripts depending on the broken-by-default behavior. Kind of like the Windows API.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams: just noticed. Interesting.